# Javascript Filter Non-Array JSON Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, filter

I am trying to filter non-array JSON object as the following snippet

```js
const filter = { filterRows: ['one'] };

const templateMapper = {
  'one': {
    title: 'one',
  },
  'two': {
    title: 'two',
  },
  'three': {
    title: 'three',
  },
}

const filterDialogView = filter.filterRows;
const filterTemplateMapper = [templateMapper].filter(row => !filterDialogView.includes(row));
console.log(filterTemplateMapper);
```

But it's not filtering

I am getting following output

```
[
  {
    "one": {
    "title": "one"
  },
  "two": {
    "title": "two"
  },
  "three": {
    "title": "three"
  }
 }
]
```

Desire output

```
 {
  "two": {
    "title": "two"
  },
  "three": {
    "title": "three"
  }
 }
```

I want to filter row based on `filterRows` for example if filterRows contain `one` as above JSON  then `one` should be removed from the `templateMapper`

Comment: where's the JSON? all I see is an object ... and objects can't be filtered using Array.filter because objects don't have filter method

Comment: i am using [templateMapper] see the above code i used [] arrays

Comment: Yeah, but that array has one entry - the WHOLE object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**Object.fromEntries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to build object back from filtered entries

***Here idea is:-***

- First get the entries from template object
- Filter the entries based on filter value
- Use **Object.fromEntries** to build object from filtered entries

```js
const filter = { filterRows: ['one'] };

const template = {'one': {title: 'one',},'two': {title: 'two',},'three': {title: 'three',}}

const filterDialogView = filter.filterRows;
const final = Object.entries(template).filter(([row])=> !filterDialogView.includes(row))
console.log(Object.fromEntries(final));
```

If you environment doesn't support Object.fromEntries you can use this

```js
const filter = { filterRows: ['one'] };

const template = {'one': {title: 'one',},'two': {title: 'two',},'three': {title: 'three',}}

const filterDialogView = filter.filterRows;
const final = Object.entries(template).filter(([row])=> !filterDialogView.includes(row))

const output = final.reduce((op,[key,value])=>{
  op[key] = value
  return op
},{})
console.log(output);
```

Comment: This is **the best answer** (I was going to post identical code) - I'd add some remarks about `Object.fromEntries` too

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks mate :) i have added some description about code and related link,

Comment: @CodeManiac i am getting this error Object.fromEntries is not a function in Node.JS

Comment: @user11229655 which version of node you're using mate ?

Comment: i am using node v10.15.2

Comment: @CodeManiac i tried in REPL.it node ver seems issue with v10.15.2 . also tried in react its working fine thanks

Comment: @user11229655 i am not sure about compatibility with node, if it is not compatible with  this version you can add polyfill for `Object.fromEntries` or you can use `reduce` to build object

Answer (score 2):

You could [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the object first. Then use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create a new object from those filtered entries.

```js
const filter = { filterRows: ['one'] };

const templateMapper = {
  'one': {
    title: 'one',
  },
  'two': {
    title: 'two',
  },
  'three': {
    title: 'three',
  },
}

const filteredObject = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(templateMapper).filter(([k]) => !filter.filterRows.includes(k))
)

console.log(filteredObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a copy of the `templateMapper` object, then iterate through the `filterRows` and delete each associated key:

```js
const filter = {
  filterRows: ['one']
};

const templateMapper = {
  'one': {
    title: 'one',
  },
  'two': {
    title: 'two',
  },
  'three': {
    title: 'three',
  },
};


const filterTemplateMapper = { ...templateMapper };
filter.filterRows.forEach((key) => {
  delete filterTemplateMapper[key];
});
console.log(filterTemplateMapper);
```

(also, as comment notes, [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/))

Comment: This mutates the object rather than creating a new one, which is different from how the filter method works.

Comment: It does not mutate the original object - the `{ ...templateMapper }` creates a copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can `filter()` objects. You should `filter()` the entries of object and then convert it to object again using `Object.fromEntries()`

```js
const filter = { filterRows: ['one'] };

const templateMapper = { 'one': { title: 'one', }, 'two': { title: 'two', }, 'three': { title: 'three', }, }

const filterDialogView = filter.filterRows;
const filterTemplateMapper = Object.fromEntries(
             Object.entries(templateMapper)
                   .filter(row => !filterDialogView.includes(row[0].title))
             );
console.log(filterTemplateMapper);
```

If `Object.fromEntries()` is not supported by your browser then use `reduce()`

```js
const filter = { filterRows: ['one'] };

const templateMapper = { 'one': { title: 'one', }, 'two': { title: 'two', }, 'three': { title: 'three', }, }

const filterDialogView = filter.filterRows;
const filterTemplateMapper = Object.entries(templateMapper)
                   .filter(row =>!filterDialogView.includes(row[0].title))
                   .reduce((ac,[k,v]) => (ac[k] = v,ac),{});
console.log(filterTemplateMapper);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way:

```js
const filter = { filterRows: ['one'] };

const templateMapper = {
  'one': {
    title: 'one',
  },
  'two': {
    title: 'two',
  },
  'three': {
    title: 'three',
  },
}

// Convert object templateMapper to array with key
const keyArrayTemplateMapper = Object.keys(templateMapper);

// Filter key array
const filterKey = keyArrayTemplateMapper.filter(key => !filter.filterRows.includes(key));

// Using reduce method to return new array
const output = filterKey.reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = templateMapper[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: All the answers here are downvoted except one. Try adding explanation of the code.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, only thing missing is some explanation mate, it is considered as good practice to add explanation to your answer as these will help future readers

Comment: I get it, added some explanation. Thank you guys.

Comment: @Scofield you can make your code as executable code snippet [read here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), and here comes your rewards for well detailed answer

Answer (score -1):

Instead of modifying the original object create a copy of it and delete the unwanted keys. For delete you can use `delete` keyword. Iterated the `filterRows` array and then use `delete` to remove the keys from the copied object

```js
const filter = {
  filterRows: ['one']
};

const templateMapper = {
  'one': {
    title: 'one',
  },
  'two': {
    title: 'two',
  },
  'three': {
    title: 'three'
  },
}


let newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(templateMapper));
filter.filterRows.forEach(function(item) {
  if (newObj.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    delete newObj[item]
  }
});
console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score -1):

The `filter()` function is only available on arrays. In order to get the same behaviour with an object, you need to use the object's `entries()`.

```js
const filter = {
  filterRows: ['one']
}

const templateMapper = {
  'one': {
    title: 'one',
  },
  'two': {
    title: 'two',
  },
  'three': {
    title: 'three',
  },
}

const filteredMapper = Object.entries(templateMapper).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  // if the key is not in the filtered list, add this entry to the object
  if (!filter.filterRows.includes(key)) {
    acc[key] = value
  }

  return acc
}, {}) // pass in empty object as initial value of accumulator

console.log(filteredMapper)
```

The way this works is we first get the `entries` (key/value pairs) from `templateMapper`. We then take those entries and `reduce` them. A reduce takes several arguments including an "accumulator" which is what collects the fields we want to keep. We "destructure" `key` and `value` so that we can check if the key is in the filter list. If it is not going to be filtered, we add it ot the accumulator. We then return the accumulator for the next iteration of the reduce. Finally, we pass in an empty object as the initial value for the accumulator on the first iteration.